# Adding searchable map to Wordpress

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am a novice at fusion tables and google maps APIs, so hopefully the answer is straight forward! I have used fusion tables to create a map of data points and added a search function.

However, the map only appears briefly before disappearing to be replaced by a "Sorry, something went wrong message".  I have reviewed the code and can't work out where the error is.

Please could someone take a look and advise what needs to change?.

Here is the link to the page: https://www.enablie.co.uk/map-test/

My code is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    #map-canvas { width:800px; height:800px; }
    .layer-wizard-search-label { font-family: sans-serif };
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var layer_0;
    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.90081096506728, -0.8806991343750425),
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      layer_0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "col2",
          from: "1LP8RhZ3QlYREIJB3e1xogaHWVmL8qxAUjKW1R6XE"
        },
        map: map,
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      });
    }
    function changeMap_0() {
      var whereClause;
      var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string_0').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
      if (searchString != '--Select--') {
        whereClause = "'School Name' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" + searchString + "'";
      }
      layer_0.setOptions({
        query: {
          select: "col2",
          from: "1LP8RhZ3QlYREIJB3e1xogaHWVmL8qxAUjKW1R6XE",
          where: whereClause
        }
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  </head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <label class="layer-wizard-search-label">
        School Name
        <input type="text" id="search-string_0">
        <input type="button" onclick="changeMap_0()" value="Search">
      </label> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your map init with AppId & AppSecret keys ? You must call Google App using this on init of your page (see this Google Map Api JS)
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Comment: Thanks - you were right.  I had not added the initMap code to the body.  I have added this (with my API Key) and it now appears to be working.

Comment: Glad to hear that, don't hesitate to close your answer ;)